# Make element wide enough to contain absolutely positioned elements

Tags: css, css-position

If I have a `div#child` that's positioned at `left: 5000px`, and my window is narrower than that, is it possible for my `div#parent` to be wide enough to contain its child?

A `width: 100%` is only as wide as the body, which doesn't contain the child. I don't know the width/position of the child. I'd prefer not to use JavaScript (but if I have to, how?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely-positioned elements are no longer part of the layout. The parent has no idea how large the child is. Yes, you need to use JavaScript to adjust the width of the parent based on the size and position of the child.

parentWidth = childWith + childLeft

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should use JavaScript/jQuery for your goal. Here is a sample solution in jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/hU2TV/

**CSS**

```
#parent {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
}
#child {
    position: absolute;
    left: 700px;
    background-color:blue;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

**JS**

```
(function ($) {
    var child = $('#child'), parent = $('#parent');
    if (child.offset().left + child.width() > parent.width()) {
        parent.width(child.offset().left + child.width());
    }
}($));
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent"><div id="child"></div></div>
```

Best regards!